# VBA: Select Value 25 Cells To Left

Tags: excel, vba

How do I select the value from a cell 25 columns to the left of my active cell? Same row.

```
Range("AF1").Select
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
For i = 26 To 2 Step -1
    value = Range(rc[-i]).Value
```

Is my current train of thought. I want to run through every cell until I'm 2 away.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with VBA, but I believe "AF1" has an integer equivalent that you could do simple math on, e.g. X-25. However, I'm not sure I follow your question based on your example solution. Do you want to select the whole range or just the individual value?

Comment: @JacobBarnes just the individual value.

Comment: `Range("AF1").OffSet(0, -25).Value` will be the value in the cell 25 columns to the left of cell AF1 or, because you have done a `Select` (bad idea doing that) you could use `Selection.Offset(0, -25).Value`.  To use `-i`, you would adjust the offset to be `-i` instead of `-25`

Comment: @YowE3K So if I stick not selecting, but simple posting the range within the for-loop, I should be okay?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on what else you are going to do with the code - e.g. if the `1` in `AF1` isn't fixed, but is also going to be used in a loop, you might consider using `Cells(rowno, "AF").Offset(0, -i).Value`, or maybe just use `Cells(rowno, 32 - i).Value`, etc (where `rowno` is a variable).  There's a lot of ways to do it, but `Select` and `Activate` are rarely a good thing to use - see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/6535336)

Answer (score 3):

you would use the offset property. i.e.

```
Sub getOffset()
  Range("AF1").Select
  ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-25).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't like the use of `Select` and `Activate`, but +1 for recommending `Offset`